# How to get a trubo_stream response when clicking on a link within a turbo_frame? (SOLVED)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails

I have a controller with an action `search` and two views for this action:

- search.html.slim
- search.turbo_stream.slim

In `search.html.slim` I have a turbo-frame with a link to this same action like:

```
h1 Title

turbo-frame#results
  = link_to "search", search_path
  = "default result"
```

In `search.turbo_stream.slim`

```
= turbo_stream.replace :results
  = link_to "search again", search_path
  = "new results!"
```

When I click on the link "search", the controller action respond with the view `search.html.slim` and not `search.turbo_stream.slim`...

How to get a turbo_stream response (i.e. a response using `search.turbo_stream.slim`) by clicking on the link "search" ?

Comment: just a note: `turbo-frame` is unnecessary in this example. and it should be `turbo_stream.update`, not `turbo_stream.replace`.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: add an attribute `data-turbo-stream` to the link,
https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/streams#streaming-from-http-responses

Links become

```
= link_to "search", search_path, 'data-turbo-stream': ''
```